# Man from interplanetary tourism ring goes native, fights own people

Tags: story-identification, aliens, novel

I wonder if anyone knows this book that I read about 30 (possibly more) years ago:
A race of people who have generated large wealth on their planet by running tourist operations on other planets. They fabricate ruins and 'terraform' new worlds to set them up for tourism.

These people see themselves as superior in many ways including physical. The reality is that they are soft and overconfident. An agent of one company visits a planet they are intending to prepare for tourism but discovers indigenous people. He is taken prisoner by the natives but joins their fight against his own people to protect the planet and their survival. The indigenous people with his help discover a super-weapon planetary defense system and destroy the invaders.

My recollection may be flawed, but I think this was the gist of it.

I also remembered that in the story I am looking for, the native people are the (now primitive) decendants of an advanced society that has (somehow) been destroyed.

Comment: Avatar, Dances With Wolves, Pocahontas, Fern Gully...

Comment: I'm curious, a hundred years ago, did we have that much popular culture that was so negative about our society? Or is this self-hatred a fairly modern invention?

Comment: Some similarities with [Lloyd Biggle's *Monument*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monument_(novel)), but many of the details don't match.

Comment: There are similarities with "Avatar".  Lloyd Biggle's "Monument" is closer (thanks Daniel I will add that one to my reading list). That reference has reminded me that in the story I am looking for, the native people are the (now primitive) decendants of an advanced society that has (somehow) been destroyed.

Comment: Very vaguely similar to "The Heaven Makers" by Frank Herbert, but not really.

Comment: It reminds me a little bit of "Come Hunt an Earthman" by Phillip E. High, but the tourism is Earth being used as a hunting preserve and no ruins are fabricated. But there is a turncoat of sorts

Comment: Apropos 'is this self-hatred a modern invention', I would say, think of Rousseau's launching the 'cult of the noble savage', or the quantity of writing before world war 1, essentially hoping for a war, feeling it would lead to a cleaner, more honourable society. So, no, probably not.